# Migrating Hadoop Clusters from Big Insights to Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, cloudera, distcp

What are the best approaches to migrate clusters of size 1 TB from Big Insights to Cloudera.

Cloudera being a kerborized cluster.

The current approach which we are following is through batches: 
a. Take the cluster and move it to Unix filesystem
b. SCP to Cloudera filesystem
c. Dump from cloudera file system to cloudera HDFS

This is not an effective approach

Comment: can this be done through distcp with cloudera being kerberized?

Answer (score 0):

Distcp does work with a kerberized cluster

However it's not clear if you actually have 333GB x3 replicas = 1TB or actually 1TB of raw data.

In either case, you're more than welcome to purchase an external 4TB (or more) drive and `copyToLocal` every file on your cluster, then upload it anywhere else.

Comment: Personally, 1TB is not enough to justify using Hadoop unless you just happen to have 5 Machines with 320GB SSDs

Comment: Am not sure of Hadoop usecase about the capacity. However, from the solution perspective, if distcp works then its well and good. Is there any firewall that needs to be opened for distcp?

Comment: Probably, https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/install_ports_distcp.html